# Neovim: remapping to paste from system clipboard pastes incorrectly

Tags: neovim

In my `init.vim` I have this section:

```
let mapleader=";"

" copies to system clipboard
vnoremap <leader>y "*y

" pastes from system clipboard
vnoremap <leader>p "*p
```

copying to my system keyboard works fine, however, when pasting using the `vnoremap` motion it either inserts an empty line or the letter `e` never what's copied in the clipboard.
however, when I do the full motion of `"*p` it pastes fine. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Are you pasting in visual mode?

Comment: Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help you further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do:

```
let mapleader=";"

" copies to system clipboard
vnoremap <leader>y "*y
nnoremap <leader>y "*y

" pastes from system clipboard
vnoremap <leader>p "*p
nnoremap <leader>p "*p
```

Remark: copying to the system clipboard and pasting from the system clipboard can be achieve with the following option:

```
set clipboard=unnamed
```

Or in Lua for Neovim:

```lua
vim.opt.clipboard = "unnamed"
```

Comment: Thanks, stupidly the issue was the `v` since I was pasting in normal mode XD. Also I've changed my init.vim -> init.lua to `vim.keymap.set({"n", "v"}, "<leader>pr", "\"*p")` thanks for your help @Vivan :)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-)

Comment: If you don't know it you could be interested by the `:set clipboard=unnamed` option that makes that by default Vim paste from and to the `*` register.

Comment: thanks I didn't know about that option to set (for anyone using lua it's `vim.opt.clipboard = "unnamed"`